# Scala Spark combine array of struct column using groupby and flatten

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scala spark dataframe that contains a column in the below format - which is an array struct that contains an Int and string.

```
fullMessage:array
    element:struct
         num:integer
         message:string
```

I want to use collect_set on the above column - fullMessage using groupBy. after the collect_set on the array column, it is returning in the below format..

```
fullMessage:array
     element:array
        element:struct
             num:integer
             message:string
```

Need help to flatten the above result to return int the same format as before applying groupBy.

Thank You.

Comment: Could you provide some original data and expected data output?

Comment: If you get your data "in the same format as before applying groupBy", it will be the same data ... so the answer to your question as asked is "do not apply groupBy". You might get some more useful answers if you provide sample input data you are trying to manipulate, the output you are trying get and the actual code you are using.